# How to AWS s3 sync from remote server to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh, server, aws-cli

I am a newbie on aws and server in general. Hope someone can help me :)

**What I want to do:**

I have some image files on remote server and I would like to copy them to aws s3 bucket.
I can ssh this remote server once I ssh intermediate server.
so it looks like

```
me(local) <-----> server1 <----> server2 where image files on
```

**What I did:**

*I first ssh server1.

*I installed aws-cli on that server, and set configure.

*Then I entered `aws s3 sync <username-I-use-for-server2>@<server2-IP>:/images/pc s3://<s3 bucket name>`

**Problem:**

What I expected was to get password prompt from server2 then sync the files in `images/pc` to s3 bucket
but I got the error saying `The user-provided path <username-I-use-for-server2>@<server2-IP>:/images/pc does not exist.`

can anyone tell me What am I doing wrong?

I've checked that I can ssh server2 and that there's files inside `/images/pc` as well.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that this is a local path to the current server.

The available combinations are `<LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>`.

You will need to run this command against a local path on the server you're trying to copy the objects from.

Remember that all this command is actually doing is running `aws s3api putObject` under the hood along with some management to perform operations such as recursion on your local disk. It does not handle any SSH interactions.

If you wanted to share any assets between servers you would need to mount them between servers (for example using an NFS mount) before you are able to sync them up, otherwise run the command on the other server.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response! 
I see. The path I typed is actually a mounted disk of some other server(so there's another server that only stores images and server2 has disk on the path that I typed in),

I did not want to install aws-cli on server2 because it’s production server of other company (although I have permission to)
but I guess there’s no choice other than running the command on server2.
Or is there any other ways to sync to AWS bucket? Such as not using AWS-cli command?

Comment: If you're able to mount the disk on your current server then yes you can run this command but the disk volume has to appear as a local volume that its being run on. The AWS CLI will still use either local path on disk or echoing the content itself :)

Comment: right, so it's either I use aws-cli on server2 or scp stuff to server1 then run aws-cli command. thanks for the help!